# Hooking up drain in dishwasher

Tags: drainage, dishwasher

I have a 2 yr old Bosch dishwasher that does not drain into the sink drain but straight down into a pipe in the ceiling below.  That pipe has the proper P trap etc and worked well for my previous dishwasher but with the Bosch there is apparently something different that makes this drain a challenge.  At first I was told it was siphoning and would not work, thus why my dishes were never clean, then I was told if I raised the drain line above the drain pipe, it would fix that. Did that and while the dishes were still not clean enough, it did seem to work(ish).  Problem is now it has plugged twice, giving me an error code on the dishwasher.  I think there is too much of a step down in pipe size so I am thinking of providing a bigger pipe to drain straight into the ABS P trap.  Will this fix my problem?  Any thoughts as I have been fiddling with this for 2 yrs.

Comment: Please post a picture of the dishwasher drain assembly.